# How to 'parse' input string and call target function?

Tags: .net

i'm developing a math/statistical software. I would like that my customer can write something like :

```
Function1(value)
```

Then, depending on the name of the function, call my internal software function. 
This seems a 'parser' right?

At the moment i'm thinking to solve it with a  code like this:

```
    switch(my_parsed_function_string) {
       case "function1":
          result = function1(value);
       case "function2": 
          result = function2(value);
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way ? 
A way where a string contained the 'function' name can be lunched without extra developer work ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's called `IDictionary`. More specifically, in your case it will be more like `IDictionary<string, Func<double>>`. Thus, your code turns into

```
var functions = new Dictionary<string, Func<double>>();
var act = functions[my_parsed_function_string].Invoke(arg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). For example:

```
interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();    
}

class Function1Command : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Function2Command : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// Bind commands
IDictionary<string, ICommand> commands = new Dictionary<string, ICommand>();
commands["Function1"] = new Function1Command(); // function 1
commands["Function2"] = new Function2Command(); // function 2
// ...
```

Then you can call your functions like this:

```
ICommand command = commands[parsedFunctionName] as ICommand;
if(command != null)
{
    command.Execute();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could declare all the functions in a single object, then reflect on it to get the method names?